# Comparisons in row or column operations in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to perform an operation across a column of a data frame wherein the output is dependent on a comparison between two values.

My data frame `dat` is arranged like this:

```
region  value1
a       0
a       0
a       6
a       7
a       3
a       0
a       4
b       5
b       1
b       0
```

I want to create a vector of factor values based in integers. The factor value should increment every time the region value changes or every time `value1` is 0. So in this case the vector I want would be equivalent to `c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)`.

I have code to make a factor vector that increments ONLY when `value1` is 0:

```
fac <- as.factor(cumsum(dat[,2]==0))
```

and I have c-style code that gets *roughly* the vector I want, but runs extremely slowly on my overall data and is just plain ugly:

```
p <- 1
facint <- 1
for (i in 2:length(dat[,2])) {
  facint <- c(facint, p)
  if (dat[i, 2]==0 || dat[i, 1] != dat[i-1, 1])
    p = p+1
  }

fac <- as.factor(facint)
```

So how can I accomplish an operation such as this when operating on every row in R-style programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cumsum(dat[,2]==0|c(FALSE,dat$region[-1]!=dat$region[-nrow(dat)]))
# [1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

Or

```
cumsum(!duplicated(dat[,1]) | dat[,2]==0)
#[1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

Comment: Or `cumsum(with(df, c(0L, diff(as.integer(region)) != 0L) | (value1 == 0L)))` if `region` is a factor.